# How to add history when cron runs to order in the backend

Tags: magento2, backend

I am writing a module when cron runs to do its job but I want to print out what cron does in the oder

Comment: You can use custom log, write log to a file.

Comment: @HoangHieu No, the customer wants me to print out what cron does when it runs in the comments history

Comment: simaly using echo